# check the value of the of the loop you are on

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have a foreach loop for an array, with an index to tell me which loop i am on, and an item to tell me the value of the loop i am on. Probably an obvious answer, but I'd like to be able to get the item from the index. How might i do this?

```
const bar1beats = [1, 0.5, 0.5, 2]

bar1beats.forEach(foreachfunction);

function foreachfunction(item, index1){

checkitemof(index1 - 1)

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that shows what precisely you're trying to do? `forEach` might not be the optimal method.

Answer (score 0):

[The `forEach` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback can accept three arguments - the item, the index, and the array itself.

```js
function foreachfunction(item, index1, theArray){
    if (index1 > 0) {
        const previousItem = theArray[index1 - 1];
        ...
    }
}
```